.Net Core Web API returns 404 in Linux Server CentOS7
I have a .net core Web API hosted on the Linux CentOS7 server, when I try to access it, it gives me 404 error.

I have created a virtual host in Post VirtualHost Include in Apache Configuration. Below is my Virtual host:
<VirtualHost 162.240.153.2:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@z.teapiocaintl.com
ServerName z.teapiocaintl.com
 # Remove DocumentRoot, it's not needed for an API
 # DocumentRoot /home/teapiocaintl/public_html/z.teapiocaintl.com/TeapiocaAPI

 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/teapiocaapi_error_log
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/teapiocaapi_access_log common

 <Directory "/">
     AllowOverride All
 </Directory>

 # Proxy requests to the .NET Core API running on localhost:<your_api_port>
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:<actual_api_port>/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:<actual_api_port>/

 ProxyPreserveHost On


I have verified that the server is configured with .net core 6 runtime.

The respective folder has Read/Write Permissions.

I am sure that the files are in the respective folder.


What else do I need to check?

This should be related to ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable. And 404 means the asp.net core application is working.
You can access the api directly to verify it. In Production environment, the swagger ui page not showing by default.
You can achieve this by deleting the app.Environment.IsDevelopment() condition.


Thanks for your comment. I have modified the code as per your instruction and uploaded it the same Folder.

No. The issue still remains same

Hi @Siva Does the defaul tapi(like WeatherForecast ) can be accessed or not ?

No it can't be accessed.

Hi @Siva , Usually the 404 means the application is running well. So please share me the url you are trying ? And also share me the code about that method(include the controller and method, some thing url like https://ip/WeatherForecast, and share the WeatherForecast controller).

https://z.teapiocaintl.com/TeapiocaAPI/api/Roles/GetRoles?userId=0&languageId=1

Is it a sub application? Could you try
z.teapiocaintl.com/api/Roles/…  this url for testing.

Yes it is the sub URL. And the above API is not working

Hi @Siva Try the solution above, then try to access the url https://z.teapiocaintl.com/TeapiocaAPI/swagger again.

The issue seems to be in creating the Virtual Host. I have hosted the same API on my local server. It's working fine. I have created a folder(TeapiocaAPI) in the Linux server and after my study, I found that the API folder needs to be a Virtual host. My guess is the issue is with the Virtual Host. Please correct me if I am wrong.

@Siva I'm not sure if sub application is supported under linux.
